# How do I install DNS and setup nameservers on CentOS 5.5 64 bit?

Tags: domain-name-system, centos, nameserver

I want to setup what I think is DNS on my CentOS 64bit server, so I could start setting up websites on my server.

How do I setup DNS, and then how do I setup multiple websites on that server?

I know I need DNS, and VirtualHosts with apache, but I don't know how to set it up? Is there a free control panel that I can instlal that can do this?

Basically:

How do I install DNS on centos, so that it works with having virtualhosts or whatever so I can host multiple websites

Sorry for the confusion!

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure you want to manage these things yourself or just pay for cheap web hosting?  These are not simple tasks with short or simple answers.

Comment: Even if you do want to host the web sites, you probably really don't want to host DNS, since most domain name registrars now provide that for free as a basic service included with your annual domain name fee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to install bind via yum for dns
for web sites depends what you need but generally 
you need

apache( httpd)
php
mysql
php-mysql

all can be installed with yum